# Superposition theorem problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, superposition

[image]

The task is to calculate *i* here, and the answer is 0.5A (specifically -0.5 due to its direction) but I have no idea how to get that. I've tried separate calculations of the circuit with only 1 voltage source and adding them up but I seem to be getting 1A. Any hints or tips?

Comment: No, you short out a voltage source to deactivate it. You open a current source deactivate it.

Comment: When the 6V is *deactivated*, 1A flows from the 3V source and out of that, 0.5A flows through the middle resistor. When the 3V source is deactivated, 2A flows from the 6V source and out of that (-)1A flows through the middle resistor. So the net current is 0.5 - 1A = -0.5A ?

Answer (score 1):

By superposition, the 3V source is contributing 1A to the system and the 6V source is contributing 2A to the system.

You need to figure out which directions those flow and where they split.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular  circuit ,you can use superposition theorem and symmetricity to solve instantly

So trick is

You can split 6volt voltage source into (3+3)v and if you observe circuit carefully you'll find that effect of 3v(on left) voltage source  is cancelled by effect of 3v(on right due to splitting) source and only effect of 3v source right) is there  due to Symmetricity in circuit

So now your equivalent circuit Will consist of only 3v source (right) and due to this source current of  (-.5)A obtained

Comment: Clever, you've split differential and common mode voltages :)